# I can't remove hover effect when I resize the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, hover

I add a hover effect to a div when the screen is smaller. When the screen is resized to become bigger, the div turns into a search box, and the hover effect is supposed to go away. The problem is that the hover effect still continues.

See [here - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/carnvall/ezn42a35/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Ara">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: auto;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 150px;
}

div#search i {
  font-size: 25px;
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div#search input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  div#search {
    right: 40px;
    width: 32px;
    padding: 13.5px;
  }
  div#search input {
    display: none;
  }
  div#search i {
    margin: 5px;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  searchHover();

  $(window).resize(function() {

    searchHover();
  });
});

function searchHover() {
  var width = $(window).width() + 17;

  if (width < 1280) {
    $('div#search').on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#00aeef',
        'transition': '0.5s',
        'border-color': '#00aeef',
        'color': 'white',
        'border-radius': '5px'
      });
    });

    $('div#search').on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'transparent',
        'transition': '0.5s',
        'border-color': '#333',
        'color': '#333',
        'border-radius': '0px'
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't recreate the error using your fiddle. Looks like it works on chrome osx

Comment: It works fine on Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Provide your OS and browser, please.

Comment: Do you have any idea about cause ? I tried edge,firefox and chrome and I have a still problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, then I think I solved it. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezn42a35/2/).

Your problem was that you forgot the `else` clause:

```
if (width < 1280) {
  $('div#search').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '#00aeef',
      'transition': '0.5s',
      'border-color': '#00aeef',
      'color': 'white',
      'border-radius': '5px'
    });
  });

  $('div#search').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'transparent',
      'transition': '0.5s',
      'border-color': '#333',
      'color': '#333',
      'border-radius': '0px'
    });
  });
} else {
  $('div#search').off('mouseover mouseout');
}
```

Without the else clause, you set the event listeners when the width is less than 1280, but you never turn them off when the width is greater or equal.

You can see it more easily in [full screen mode](https://jsfiddle.net/ezn42a35/2/embedded/result/).

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you :).